# Не появляется меню

Tags: php, html

При изменении файла с .html на .php  - перестает работать всплывающее меню. При нажатии на иконку ничего не происходит. Все файлы подгружаются. Сам код выглядит следующим образом :

```
<div class="fusion-mobile-menu-icons">
<a href="#" class="fusion-icon fusion-icon-bars" aria-label="Toggle mobile menu" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

Comment: причём здесь php? что это за код без всяких js? он сам по себе работать в принципе не может